# "Dabble" in a positive sense

Tags: word-choice, connotation, word-usage

Can the word "dabble" be used in a positive sense?

As in,

> A true "master of all trades", he has
>   dabbled in several fields &
>   contributed to numerous scientific
>   advances.

Comment: ..when is dabble used negatively?

Comment: I agree with @HaL; _dabble_ doesn't really have a negative connotation. E.g., _The World's Most Interesting Man_ might be said to habitually _dabble_ in art, extreme sports, political intrigue, and exotic women, but no one in their right mind would call that a bad thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dabbled in` carries a not negative connotation, but a somewhat dismissive tone. As in, "I dabbled in witchcraft and it wasn't for me." Dabbling doesn't have a sense of permanency to it in terms of one's interest in a matter. That said, "I dabbled in novice physics books and am a bit wiser for the effort" would certainly bear a positivity about it.

Mostly, it just depends on how one extends or qualifies the impact of dabbling. Dabbling seems to have a certain antecedent>consequent structure to it that implies the positive/negative; i.e. with both example phrases above there is no +/- value until the "and..." statement created one.

Answer (score 1):

In BE it is a positive sense - to dabble in something is gentlemanly.
Only a foreigner would need to exert themselves.

(The above may account for Britain's expected performance in a certain sporting event to be held in London in 2012)