# Not "enthusiast", but what?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word for:

> someone who enjoys **thinking** or **talking** about a thing more than
>   actually **doing** the thing itself.

Most of the answers I have seen so far address the distinction between one who is serious about a subject and one who only wants to bear the distinction of being an expert in the subject.  I was imagining that the person being described is quite serious, e.g. Gregory House is an excellent diagnostician, but not a great doctor.

Comment: Armchair quarterback.

Comment: I wouldn't say your question is a duplicate of these, but they're somewhat related. You might find what you're looking for here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95043/dabbler-without-the-negative-connotation/95044#95044

Comment: ...and here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216667/what-single-noun-denotes-a-person-who-is-interested-in-something

Comment: Being considered falling into the "autistic spectrum", that is what I frequently do. It is true that we tend to speak in detail about a subject even though we could be unenthusiastic about the subject itself. It is a pity people think we are trying to "show-off", which is far from the case. To me, I see it as just another normal walk in the park, describing in precision a subject I have no interest in. It is the act of dissection and analysis that fascinates us, even if the subject does not.

Comment: It helps me componentize, to break a subject up into components that already exist in my multidimensional matrix of buckets, and frequently the subject requires buckets not already existing, I would visually traverse the matrix to find where in my mind to appropriately fit in a new bucket. It is fascinating to me - every new encounter, I look for existing buckets in my head that fit parts of that new encounter, and then after fitting into existing buckets, there would be a big uncategorised uncomponentized blob, waiting for me to quantize the leftover blob into components.

Comment: The proof of the pudding is the eating. -Cervantes

Comment: I'm sure there are several idioms of the form "All [X] and no [Y]".  But I can't seem to remember any of them. Can you?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: They are all [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_talk_and_no_action). But they all seem slightly different, however OP's context is not clear also. Maybe, "all talk and no action" is a bit more suitable.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Dabble" in a positive sense](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21084/dabble-in-a-positive-sense)

Comment: Maybe "hobbyist"?

Comment: Philosopher?  :)

Comment: Those who can, do; those who can't, teach.

Comment: Can you specify the connotation?

Comment: You need to specify whether you want a noun or adjective (or possibly something else).

Comment: I like "all hat and no cattle".

Comment: I try to be really conscientious about ultimately selecting the best answer when I post a question on stackexchange, but it may simply be that no such word really exists.  Sorry gang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mycroft is Sherlock Holmes's older brother who never plays an active part.

'Academically speaking' implies action is not part of the plan.

Comment: I have to say, if we were to coin a term, a "Mycroft" would be about perfect.

Answer (score 4):

While the everyone else is making things happen, the *[commentator](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/commentator)* and the *[analyst](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/analyst)* are talking up a storm:

> *analyst*
>
> n
>   1. a person who analyses or is skilled in *[analysis](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/analysis)*
>
> *commentator*
>
> n.
>   1. a person who discusses news, sports, or other topics on TV or radio.
>   2. a person who makes *[commentaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/commentary?q=commentaries)*.
>
> *Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary*

Comment: Critic had occurred to me, but seemed a bit cynical.  I guess I was searching for a word with a bit of sting, but also that expresses some of the enthusiasm our subject carries.

Answer (score 3):

Some calls these folks *[bloviators](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bloviator)*:

> 1. A public figure, such as a politician or an actor, who makes outlandish, strident statements on issues, thinking that the average
>      man will care about their opinions.
> 2. Someone who pontificates about issues of which they are uninformed, yet pretend to be expert.
> 3. Pompous blowhard, using their celebrity to speak about topics on which they are totally unqualified.
>
> *Urban Dictionary*

In *The Washington Post, [Is Bill O'Reilly Making Things Up Or Just Bloviating?](http://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/style/is-bill-oreilly-making-things-up-or-just-bloviating/2015/02/27/bd5e7f66-bea4-11e4-b274-e5209a3bc9a9_story.html)*, February 27, 2015, By Paul Farhi:

> I’ve been there,” he once said. “That’s really what separates me from
>   most of these other ***bloviators***. I *bloviate*, but I *bloviate* about stuff
>   I’ve seen. They *bloviate* about stuff that they haven’t.
>
> ***Emphasis*** mine

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a term that's fairly neutral, or at least less pejorative.

Answer (score 1):

Various levels of cynical sarcasm can be achieved with words that imply the uselessness of talk compared to action.

*[Chatterbox](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chatterbox)*:

> n.
> An extremely talkative person.

*[Magpie](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/magpie)*

> n.
> 3. A person who chatters.

*[Windbag](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/windbag)*

> n.
> 2. Slang A talkative person who communicates nothing of substance or interest.

*[Blowhard](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blowhard)*

> n. Informal
> A boaster or braggart.

Although *blowhard* denotes *braggadocio*, those who talk without action normally present an arrogance that simulates boasting.

All definitions from *American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition*

Answer (score -1):

**Wannabe** fits under some circumstances.

[Free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wannabe):

> a. a person who desires to be, or be like, someone or something else: a group of Marilyn Monroe wannabes.
>   b. (as modifier): a wannabe film star.

Comment: Nothing about *wannabe* suggests they prefer talking to doing.

Comment: Never met a wannabe doctorate, huh? Some of these students want it *so* bad; talk constantly about how great they'll be, but are never willing to put in the effort. I'm sure it happens in non-educational settings as well.